# Partition a set in $\mathbb R^2$ into equal measure sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

1. Given a finite measure measurable set $E$ in $\mathbb R^2$ can we find a subset $A$ such that $m(A) = m(E \setminus A)$?

2.The question given to me is : given a positive $L^1$ function $f$ on $\mathbb R^2$ can we find a subset $A$ such that integral of $f$ over $A$ = integral of $f$ over $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$?

Defining a new measure as integral of $f$, the sum reduces to proving part 1.
Now what?

Note : Everything above is wrt Lebesgue measure.

Comment: If $m$ is the Dirac measure of any point, then it is clearly impossible.

Comment: For absolutely continuous measures it will work, though (and the term pretty much already tells you what to do).

Comment: I mean with Lebesgue measure. Maybe I should have specified.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**.  Let $m$ be any measure on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $m(L)=0$, for every vertical line $L⊆\mathbb R^2$ (such
as any measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue's measure).  Then, for every measurable set
$E⊆\mathbb R^2$, with $m(E)<\infty$,  there exists a measurable subset $A⊆E$ such that $m(A)=m(E)/2$.

*Proof*.
For each interval $I\subseteq \mathbb R$, consider the vertical strip
$$
  V_I=I\times \mathbb R,
  $$
and let
$$
  E_I = V_I\cap E.
  $$

Fixing  any real number $t_0$, notice that
$$
  \bigcap_{t>t_0} (-\infty, t] = (-\infty, t_0]
  \qquad \text { and }   \qquad
  \bigcup_{t<t_0} (-\infty, t] = (-\infty, t_0).
  $$
Consequently
$$
  \bigcap_{t>t_0} E_{(-\infty, t]} = E_{(-\infty, t_0]}
  \qquad \text { and }   \qquad
  \bigcup_{t<t_0} E_{(-\infty, t]} = E_{(-\infty, t_0)}.
  $$
Using that $E$ has finite measure we deduce that
$$
  \inf_{t>t_0} m (E_{(-\infty, t]}) = m (E_{(-\infty, t_0]})
  \qquad \text { and }   \qquad
  \sup_{t<t_0} m (E_{(-\infty, t]}) = m (E_{(-\infty, t_0)}).
  $$
Because positive measures are monotonic functions we also get
$$
  \lim_{t\to t_0^+} m (E_{(-\infty, t]}) = m (E_{(-\infty, t_0]})
  \qquad \text { and }   \qquad
  \lim_{t\to t_0^-} m (E_{(-\infty, t]}) = m (E_{(-\infty, t_0)}).
  $$
Regarding the function
$
  f(t):= m  (E_{(-\infty, t]}),
  $
we conclude from the first identity above that  $f$ is right-continuous.  Moreover,  referring to the degenerate interval
$[t_0,t_0]$,  observe that
$$
  m (E_{(-\infty, t_0]})=   m (E_{(-\infty, t_0)}) +   m (E_{[t_0 t_0]})= m (E_{(-\infty, t_0)}),
  $$
where we have used the hypothesis to conclude that $m (E_{[t_0 t_0]})= 0$.
We therefore  also have that $f$ is left-continuous, hence continuos.

Since
$$
  \lim_{t\to-\infty}f(t) = 0
  \qquad \text { and }   \qquad
  \lim_{t\to\infty}f(t) = m  (E),
  $$
we can now employ the intermediate value Theorem to obtain  some $t_1$ such that $f(t_1)=m (E)/2$.   The desired
set $A$ mentioned  in the statement can then  taken to be $A=E_{(-\infty,t_1]}$.